# Can the android NDK compile kernel module source?

Tags: android, android-ndk

I want make a dynamic loaded kernel module for android.
I don't want to install a linux, I just have cygwin and android NDK.

Comment: Because the linux don't have a kernel ABI, so you have to compile module to every individual kernel. .

Comment: can I able to load LKM from application in rooted phone,to interfere system calls. any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just now I found [this URL](http://www.mail-archive.com/android-kernel@googlegroups.com/msg00801.html) where the user has attempted loading LKM and was successful, though on Android (Kernel core: 2.6.29) and I think it was on Linux and not on Cygwin. Hope you get it too!

There is one more resource [here](http://finsframework.org/mediawiki/index.php/Android#Building_LKMs_for_a_specific_build_of_Android) and [here too](http://finsframework.org/mediawiki/index.php/Android_Work_Log#LKM_.28Loadable_Kernel_Modules.29)!.

All the best!

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is possible to build kernel modules with the NDK. Note, this works best with a Linux system (I'm told Linux x86_64 is the supported environment) because it's harder to cross-compile kernel code on case sensitive filesystems (such as those that come by default on Windows and Mac systems), and because building kernel modules requires building ELF-manipulation binaries (modpost) which require ELF headers typically only present on Linux. 
That said...

First you need to get the source code to the same exact kernel on your device, and make sure that the configuration is the same as your device. (otherwise there's a chance you will confuse the build system)

Second, you need to determine where in your Android NDK the cross-compiler toolchain is. Here's how I found mine:

```
$ cd $NDK_HOME
$ find . | grep '\-gcc$'
./toolchains/arm-eabi-4.4.0/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-eabi-gcc
./toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc
```

(note, `$NDK_HOME` is where I installed the Android NDK)

Third, you need to add the `$NDK_HOME/toolchains/arm-eabi-4.4.0/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin` directory (or wherever it is on your system) to your PATH environment variable.

Then you need to export two environment variables:

```
export ARCH=arm 
export CROSS_COMPILE=arm-eabi-
```

(note, the `arm-eabi-` prefix is the same as what we saw in the `find` command. When the kernel is built, commands such as `gcc` and `ld` will be prefixed with this. Note, if you were building for an x86 platform I expect you would have to adjust these. I have only built modules for ARM.)

Next, you should compile the kernel. (to do this, I pulled down `/proc/config.gz` from my Android device, ran `zcat config.gz > .config` within the kernel source directory, then ran `make menuconfig && make`.) Kernel build gurus may know some shortcuts here, but I wasn't able to set up the kernel source directory correctly for building a module without doing an actual build. (If the kernel in your build tree matches your device, you don't have to actually update the kernel, you can just insert the modules.)

Last, I used the normal process to build the kernel modules from source. Typically kernel modules will have a parameterized build which will read in the kernel source tree directory somehow, then invoke the build. At that point, as long as the kernel source tree is set up correctly and `ARCH` and `CROSS_COMPILE` are set up, your module should build!

Good luck with this. I'm sure there is some per-device variance.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this [URL](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/0dc888d0b1673185), Android developer suggests to go for virtual Ubuntu image for this than cygwin.

Comment: No, I don't want compile android, just a new kernel module.

Comment: Sorry, I have not come across such requirement so far.. Since I had the entire source, I just added my modules at respective driver folders and got my custom android image.