# How to link against native code in Android using NDK?

Tags: android, android-ndk, native, dynamic-linking

I was tinkering around a bit and thought it was be an interesting project to augment functionality provided by specific services in the Android source, namely Wifi, Location, and Power services.

I am able to compile native code without issue if it is entirely self contained. However, once I try to include headers that are either not traditional linux or libc headers I run into issues at compile-time related locating these files.

For example, the native wifi implementation in Android can be found at `hardware/libhardware_legacy/wifi/wifi.c` within the source tree. Of course, this source may further include headers and things that result in further location issues.

Similarly, some native power functions are located at `hardware/libhardware_legacy/power/power.c`.

What is the standard was for linking against these native implementations when using the NDK? My second idea was to possibly define at compile-time to dynamically link against the loaded wifi/location/power-related *.so, but I have not done this before and am unsure how to do it; this may be an option, though, if I can figure out which shared object implements this native code.

Comment: Q: Is the source you're referring to for *kernel* modules, or is it *user space* code.  You can use NDK to call the latter, but not, generally, the former.  Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4865469/can-the-android-ndk-compile-kernel-module-source) for more details.

Comment: @paulsm4, is there an easy way to tell? I imagine that these implementations reside within *kernel-space* since it's obviously not desirable for users to muck around with things like location services. In this case, I should be looking at building a kernel-module wrapper, or similar. If you cannot link against *kernel-space* code, how can one build a kernel module using the NDK?

Answer (score 1):

The two specific files that you mention belong to user-space, but they are part of a library that is not 'documented'. You see them because Android is open-source, but you cannot be sure these implementations will be the same on all Android devices. Even their interfaces may change without notice.

Also, many libraries that are 'user space' on Android can be used only from system processes, like `mdeiaserver`. Even if you use *root access* to work around access permissions to some system resources, you can fail because system process assumes that it has full control over, e.g., camera device.

If you are building your custom ROM, you are responsible for packaging all the system libraries, including `libhardware_legacy.so`. But when you build a custom ROM you don't uss NDK, even though there are many similarities between the `Android.mk` files, and the toolchains used.

You can learn a lot about extending AOSP *[here](http://www.opersys.com/blog/extending-android-hal)*.